# Number of people over age 65 in each ZCTA for each year since 2005

Tags: data-request, us-census, population

Population and age data for zip codes are easy to find for 2010 and later. Where can I find zip code level population and age data from 2005 to 2010? Specifically, I need the number of individuals over age 65 in each zip code for each year since 2005.